# Get a single page's URL metric based on its base URL, ignoring the query string

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

The hit URL of a single page can be different like `/post/15777`, `/post/15777?fbclid=xxx` or `/post/15777?rel=notification`.

I want to get the URL `/post/15777` metric (pageviews) but could not by using the API method `getPageUrl` in `matomo api` module because it would think of them as different URL.

```
GET /?
module=API&format=JSON&method=Actions.getPageUrl&pageUrl=/post/15777&idSite=1&period=range&date=2018-12-12,2019-12-12&token_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved
Instead of method Actions.getPageUrl with pageUrl parameter, use the Actions.get method with segment parameter of pageUrl contains a specific url `segment=pageUrl=@/post/15777`

```
GET /?module=API&format=JSON&method=Actions.get&segment=pageUrl=@/post/15777&idSite=1&period=range&date=2018-12-12,2019-12-12&token_auth=xxxxx
```

Comment: Just as a note, use the "lastx" format for getting a date range, it's significantly faster on larger databases than the "datex,datey" format.

Comment: Using Mamoto just to get the pageview is really inefficient. It is slow and takes too much space for the simple task. Rather quickly build an app that do that specifically as an alternative.